# Как уменьшить размер apk в Unity с помощью app bundle и aab

Tags: unity3d, android-bundle

не могу найти необходимые мне шаги для решения проблемы.

Есть проект, весит `83МБ` в гугл консоли предложили использовать app bundle в формате `.aab` вместо `.apk` чтобы уменьшить размер установочного файла.

Я прочел документацию https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/#playcore

и от `Unity`
https://blogs.unity3d.com/ru/2018/10/03/support-for-android-app-bundle-aab-in-unity-2018-3-beta/

Но не понял каким именно образом это сделать и как это толком поможет.
Из статьи, что опубликовала `Unity`, мне просто необходимо собрать файл `.aab` и залить как `apk`, не понятно как это уменьшит размер.

В этом ресурсе (ссылка ниже) регистрируют `.pepk` файл для нового приложения, и загружают свой `.aa`b файл я же создавал ключ простым способом подписи в `Unity`

https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-app-bundle-google-play-app-signing-what-option-do-we-use-with-unity.604723/

не понятно что именно делать для правильных результатов, просто подписать тем же ключом что и подписываю `apk` и загрузить в `play market`?

Answer (score 0):

Ставишь галочку Build App Bundle (Google play) как в документации. И этот aab отправляешь вместо apk. Он автоматически гуглом форматируется в нужный формат. Ключ я тоже создавал в юнити, и он же работает.

Answer (score 0):

При отправке нового приложения гугл сам создаст ключ, а если вы пытаетесь обновить старое приложение, тот вам нужно зашифровать имеющийся ключ подписи при помощи командной строки и залить его в консоль разработчика. Вот более подробная инструкция: https://iunity3d.ru/android-app-bundle-aab-unity-3d/

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно просто создать bundle файл подписанный тем же ключом что и apk если вы делаете обновление и отправить Google. Это всё что нужно сделать!